# Redux-triggered function not registering component current state

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-state-management

## TL;DR

When a store change triggers a component function, the current component state is ignored/reset, not letting me use its state data to feed the triggered function.

## Full Description

This react-native app has a button located in a heading Appbar stack navigator, which must trigger a function that the currently focused Screen has.
The thing is that this screen is very deep within the navigation scheme, thus I decided to use Redux to directly notify the screen that the button has been pressed.
This also means that every time that this button is pressed and a store slice gets dispatched, I can trigger any function only depending on the Screen implementation.

If i use the very same function from a button within the component it works perfectly. However if I call the same function from the redux store change i get this log:

#### Console Behavior

```sh
# component loaded
false

# started writing, this is the component state
h
he
hel 
hell
hello 

#header button 'create' state change detected
true

#content as viewed by the onPressPublish function
content: ""

Error 400 - Cannot save empty content

#store reset for further use
false
```

#### Appbar

```js
export const AppBarStackNavigator = (props) => {
    const { toggle } = useSelector(toolbarSelector);
    const handleCreatePress = () => {
        dispatch(setCreate({ pressed: true }));
    }
return (
        <Appbar.Header
            style={{ backgroundColor: theme.colors.background, elevation: 0 }}
        >
                         <Button
                            icon="seed"
                            mode="contained"
                            // disabled={!contentProps.valid}
                            onPress={handleCreatePress}
                            labelStyle={{ color: 'white' }}
                            style={{
                                width: 115,
                                borderRadius: 50,
                                alignSelf: "flex-end"
                            }}>
                            Sembrar
                        </Button>
        </Appbar.Header>
    );
}
```

#### Store

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const toolbarSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'toolbar',
    initialState: {
        create: false
    },
    reducers: {
        setCreate(state, action) {
            state.create = action.payload.pressed; 
        }
    }
})

export const { setCreate } = toolbarSlice.actions;

export const toolbarSelector = state => state.toolbar

export default toolbarSlice.reducer;
```

#### The navigationally-deep component

```js
import { toolbarSelector, setCreate } from '../store/toolbar';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
// import { useFocusEffect, TabActions, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

export const DeepComponent = (props) => {
    const theme = useTheme();
    const { create } = useSelector(toolbarSelector);

    return (
        <ChildComponent {...props} create={create} setCreate={setCreate} style={{ backgroundColor: theme.colors.background }} />
    );
};
```

#### Its child (where the function is)

```js
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export const ChildComponent = (props) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [content, setContent] = useState(''));

    let payload = {};

    const onPressPublish = async () => {
        try {
            console.log(payload);
            payload = {
                ...payload,
                content,
                // images <- other component states
            }
            console.log(payload);
            const seed = await api.writeOne(payload);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            Alert.alert('Could not publish :(', error.message);
        }
        navigation.goBack();
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(props.create)
        console.log(content)
        if (props.create) {
            console.log(content)
            onPressPublish();
        }
        return () => {
            dispatch(props.setCreate({ pressed: false }));
        };
    }, [props.create])

    const onTextChange = (value, props) => {
        // ...
        setContent(value);
        // ...
    }

return (
        <TextInput 
            mode='flat'
            placeholder={inputPlaceholder}
            multiline
            onChangeText={text => onTextChange(text, props)}
            keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}
            autoFocus
            clearButtonMode='while-editing'>
            <ParsedContent content={content} />
        </TextInput>
        <Button            
            disabled={!contentProps.valid}
            onPress={onPressPublish}>
            {buttonText}
        </Button>
    )
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this: `const [content, setContent] = useState(prevState => ((prevState) ? prevState : ''));` and never use the setContent and giving a function to useState where `prefState` will never be anything but undefined so that function is pointless, may as well set it to `''` directly

Comment: You are absolutely correct @HMR .That is was left by accident from a test i did against an useEffect. I've edited it out to avoid confussion (even if its obvious that it does nothing)

Comment: setContent is never called though, I don't see why you don't just do `const seed = await api.writeOne({content:''});` because with code provided that is the only thing that can ever happen

Comment: I specified that the content variable is filled by an input, but lemme add that code too for more transparency

Comment: There you go @HMR

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions to change the code, you still have not provided any code in your question that would make sense (like the payload variable) but this may give you an idea where to go.

When you create an app with create-react-app you should have a linter that tells you when you have missing dependencies in hooks, you should not ignore these warnings:

```
//create onPressPublish when component mounts
const onPressPublish = useCallback(async (content) => {
  try {
    //removed payload as it makes no sense to create it
    //  and never use it anywhere
    //removed assigning to seed becasue it is never used anywhere
    await api.writeOne({ content });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    Alert.alert('Could not publish :(', error.message);
  }
  navigation.goBack();
}, []);
const { create, setCreate } = props;
useEffect(() => {
  if (create) {
    //passing content
    onPressPublish(content);
  }
  return () => {
    dispatch(setCreate({ pressed: false }));
  };
}, [
  //correct dependencies without linter warnings
  content,
  dispatch,
  onPressPublish,
  create,
  setCreate,
]);
```